# HDD and SSD sensibility to magnets

Tags: hard-drive

I knew that magnets removes data from hdd, but (may be strange) have never thought why.
Today I was reading comparison between HDD an SSD

> [image]

- Is it true that "An SSD is safe from any effects of magnetism"?
- Why magnets remove data from hdd?

Comment: @DaveRook SSD is sensible too? Interesting. I edited - will see what others say.

Comment: Wikipedia provides in in-depth explanation of [magnetic storage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_disk#Magnetic_recording).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A harddrive uses one or more copperlike cylinders. The stuff is the same as you have on those old video tapes and casette tapes. The head contains a magnet and by changing the magnetic field that specific position will remember the new setting forever until modified again. By placing electricity on that spot, the 0 or 1 can be read.

Becaues a magnet is used to alter the state of that position, another magnet can therefor change the magnetic field too causing the data to change enough so the cells do no longer hold the original value, which will be seen as erasing the harddrive. The files may still show as being there, but when opening them, it'll give you a read error. If the magnet reaches the porption where the File Allocation Table is stored, the files itself may be in tact, but the reference to them might be gone.

An SSD works completely different. They do not require magnets to change the 0's and 1's on the drive, and as such they can't be wiped by a magnet.